# android, automatic animation after modify property?

Tags: android, android-layout

Since I have a Button in a Layout,
I know how to modify property of a controller dynamically like

```
layout1.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)  
btn1.setPadding()
```

But it just suddenly teleport to the new position
is there any way to automatically start a animation between the previous and the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/apply-animation-on-button.html). It has translate animation from left to Right. you change it according to yours. May this helps you.